# How to run gcloud command using given configuration of a service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I have several gcloud service accounts and I'd like to add them to `gcloud config configurations list`. From what I could find on their [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations/create), I could create different configurations using command `gcloud config configurations create <config-name>`. Then I did following to add a service account to my configuration list

```
gcloud config configurations activate <config-name>
gcloud config set account <service-account-email>
gcloud config configurations activate default
```

Seems like everything is fine. But when I try to deploy something it reports error

```
gcloud app deploy <some>.yaml --configurations <config-name>
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your current active account [<service-account-email>] does not have any valid credentials
```

I have the credential file on hand but have no idea how to apply it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to active your service account credentials:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account username@development-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=service_account.json
```